# Applying a function over a column to create another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, apply

I'm trying to apply a function over a Data frame column to evaluate and classify rows values. I define the function for each scenario and apply this function over the column but I'm getting two errors.

I tried to define the function outside the loop, taking three parameters instead of one, and inside the loop, taking only one value, but they both got the same error.

```
for i in list(df['segment'].unique()): 
    temp = df.query('segment== "%s"' %i)
    for t in list(temp['area_tipe'].unique()):
        temp2 = temp.query('area_tipe== "%s"' %t)
        a = temp2.quantile(q=0.33)
        b = temp2.quantile(q=0.66)
        def classifierprice(x):
            if float(x) < a:
                rep = 'low'
            elif float(x) > a:
                if float(x) < b:
                    rep = 'medium'
            elif float(x) > b:
                rep = 'high'
            return rep 
        temp2['price_class'] = temp2['price'].map(lambda x: classifierprice(x), axis=1)

TypeError: map() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Using apply instead of map I got the same error, if I remove axis, both to apply and map, I got the following code/error:

```
for i in list(df['segment'].unique()): 
    temp = df.query('segment== "%s"' %i)
    for t in list(temp['area_tipe'].unique()):
        temp2 = temp.query('area_tipe== "%s"' %t)
        a = temp2.quantile(q=0.33)
        b = temp2.quantile(q=0.66)
        def classifierprice(x):
            if float(x) < a:
                rep = 'low'
            elif float(x) > a:
                if float(x) < b:
                    rep = 'medium'
            elif float(x) > b:
                rep = 'high'
            return rep 
        temp2['price_class'] = temp2['price'].map(lambda x: classifierprice(x))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

I'm performing the same map method in another classification that does no involve splitting the data frame and its working fine, as follow:

```
def grow(x):
    if x > 0:
        a = 'growing'
    elif x < 0:
        a = 'declining'
    else:
        a = 'constant'
    return a

insights["text"] = (insights["score"].map(grow))
```

Comment: I feel like that is just groupby ...would you like show us some sample data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the actual value there, with the `.quantile()` method we get a series object containing 1 value, but pandas does not understand that its one single value it thinks we are comparing a series and hence the error, we get the number inside using `.values[0]`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

### making some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({"area_tipe":np.random.choice(["m","n","o"],100)
                    , "price" : np.random.randint(1,10,100)    
                    , "segment":np.random.choice(["p","q","r"],100)})

### keeping the function ot of the for loop
def classifierprice(x, a, b):
    x = float(x)
    if x <= a:
        rep = 'low'
    elif a < x < b:
        rep = 'medium'
    elif x >= b:
        rep = 'high'
    return rep 

for i in list(df['segment'].unique()): 
    temp = df.query('segment== "%s"' %i)
    for t in list(temp['area_tipe'].unique()):
        temp2 = temp.query('area_tipe== "%s"' %t)

        a = temp2.quantile(q=0.33).values[0]
        b = temp2.quantile(q=0.66).values[0]
        temp2['price_class'] = temp2['price'].apply(lambda x: classifierprice(x,a,b))
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

You can do this without loops though, you will get all the output df's at once! - try this as a starter -

```
def grouped_classifierprice(df_filt):
    a = df_filt.quantile(q=0.33).values[0]
    b = df_filt.quantile(q=0.66).values[0]
    return df_filt.price.apply(lambda x: classifierprice(x,a,b))

outdf = df.groupby(["area_tipe","segment"]).apply(grouped_classifierprice)
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj ! You're the best !